# <cr> doesn't work with `normal!`

Tags: vim

I tried:

```
$ vi +'help|only|set nu|execute "normal! 48G<cr>zt"'
```

But the `zt` part doesn't apply. (48 is the `Getting Started` line)

Could someone please explain why the zt part doesn't work and why this:

```
$ vi +'help|only|set nu|execute "normal! /^Getting<cr>zt"'
```

doesn't even apply the search for `/^Getting`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `<cr>` after a `G` command.

```
vi +'help|only|set nu|execute "normal! 48Gzt"'
```

works fine for me.

Additionally, you need to specify the Enter character instead of `<cr>` (which you can write by typing `Ctrl-V` and then the `Enter` key) if you want to use search.

The command shows up like this :

```
vi +'help|only|set nu|execute "normal! /^Getting^Mzt"'
```

But the `^M` is actually the `Ctrl-v`-`Enter` binding

Comment: Thanks. Turns out the `<cr>` should have been `\r`. Also, you're right -- it's not needed in the first command, and neither is the `execute` part.

Comment: Note, when using :execute you can do :exe "norm! \<cr>" to get a literal <cr> character for :normal This can be read about at :h expr-quote

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thanks. I highly appreciate this kind of advice.